# Add CSS for particular span

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I want to add * before my Enter Firstname, for that i am using this CSS but that * is adding to both Enter Firstname, Enter Lastname, because i am adding css for span.
Please help me in this how to add css for particualr span without using id to it.

```
<style>
    .pssmailform p span:before{
    content:"* ";
    color:red;
    }
</style>

<div class="pssmailform">
<p><span>Enter Firstname</span></p>
<p><span>Enter Lastname</span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [pseudo selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) to select only the first p tag like so:

```
<style>
    .pssmailform p:first-child span:before{
        content:"* ";
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

UPDATE: if you want 2 spans out of 3 you can do:

```
<style>
    .pssmailform p:first-child span:before, .pssmailform p:nth-child(2) span:before{
        content:"* ";
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

alternatively if you want to do it for odd or even elements you can use:

```
<style>
    .pssmailform p:nth-child(odd) span:before {
        content:"* ";
        color:red;
    }

    .pssmailform p:nth-child(even) span:before {
        content:"* ";
        color:blue;
    }
</style>#
```

also if you want to do it for every 5th element you can do:

```
<style>
    .pssmailform p:nth-child(5n) span:before {
        content:"* ";
        color:red;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: hey if i want to add the same thing for two span out of three than what i need to add?

Comment: this evan and odd is not working fine for me, and that nth -child is also not working

Comment: What browser are you using?